# Format of file so that its easy to parse it

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, file-format

I have to parse some files having common format and dump data into a file. I want to know what should be its format so that parsing is easy.

What should be the file format and its parsing mechanism?

I have designed file format and its parsing mechanism as follows

**user1.txt**

```
24-07-2014
tag_1
some_data
tag_2
some_data
tag_3
some_data
end

31-07-2014
tag_1
some_data
tag_2
some_data
tag_3
some_data
end
```

Every week these files will be updated with some data

**Parsing mechanism:**

```
func()
    get index of date(passed as arg) and end(first occurence from after date)
    make a list out of it
    from this list take index of tag_1, tag_2, tag_3 and append data between tag_1 index and tag_2 index, tag_2 and tag_3, tag_3 and end in tag_1_data, tag_2_data, tag_3_data respectively

main()
    call func() for each file as argument to it.
    then dump data in list tag_1_data, tag_2_data & tag_3_data into a file
```

So file generated from this will contain data from tag_1, tag_2, tag3 from all files grouped
 seperately.

**generated_file.txt** for *python script.py 24-07-2014*

```
24-07-2014
tag_1
data from user1
data from user2
data from user3

tag_2
data from user1
data from user2
data from user3


tag_3
data from user1
data from user2
data from user3
```

**Note*** - those files user1.txt, user2.txt etc are updated with that format every week(before user enters its data) with another script so that user has to write only data(under each tag) not format and data

If u know better file format which make parsing more easy then shoot your comments.

Comment: Have you tried `json`?

Comment: All this very much depends on what your data is. Can a user arbitrarily choose the data? Are there (poential) malicious users? You can always use library functions that store data in JSON, XML or SQlite or other databases

Comment: @Mathias No malicious users and data entered by them will be simple text

Comment: @tobias_k I have used JSON in other python programs. If we use JSON for file format, then updating file with that format will be easy ?